# Which programming languages can connect to WCF?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services

I don't know about WCF but I want to switch to it.
I have written a web service using ASMX in ASP.net.Every programming language as like as php, c#,java,... can connect to my web service and use it. what about WCF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any programming language capable of sending **HTTP requests** is capable of using WCF REST.

Any programming language capable of sending **POX requests** is capable of using WCF `webHttpBinding`.

Any programming language capable of **consuming web services** is capable of using WCF `basicHttpBinding`.

Any programming language capable of compatible with `WS-*` is capable of using WCF `wsHttpBinding`.

Answer (score 3):

That depends on the configured bindings. The Basic HTTP binding behaves just like an ASMX  Web Service.

With the other binding types your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

WCF works the same way.. You expose the WSDL and you are as good as your WebService.. Offcourse there are more features in WCF and you would need to learn some of the new stuff to get it working..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a white paper for the WCF. It really helps.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ee958158.aspx

Answer (score 0):

With a WCF service you would be able to connect from other platforms as well.

Here's a quote from Wikipedia

> Interaction between WCF endpoint and
>   client is done using a SOAP envelope.
>   SOAP envelopes are in simple XML form
>   that makes WCF platform independent.